# ¿Como agregar consulta personalizada (COUNT) de SQL a linq C#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Tengo una duda con agregar un campo personalizado que se hacer en SQL pero no se en linq.

En si es un select donde filtro un usuario y agrupo por Keyword... pero necesito traer el keyword que mas se repita, de ahi que haga el count.

```
SELECT 
     UserID, 
     KeywordID, 
     COUNT(KeywordID) as count 
FROM 
     LogKeywords lk 
WHERE 
     UserID = 83 
GROUP BY 
      KeywordID ;
```

Esa consulta me trae esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso ya lo tengo en C#, pero no se como clavarle el count dentro de .Select().

Mi codigo en C# esta asi:

```
var keyword = _context.LogKeywords
                    .Where(x => x.UserID == employee.UserID)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.UserID,
                        x.Keyword.Name,
                        count = x.KeywordID.Count() //<--- aqui me aparece un error
                    })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.KeywordID);
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre una solucion haciendolo asi:

```
var lista = from l in _context.LogKeywords.Where(x => x.UserID == employee.EmployeeID).ToList()
                        group l by l.KeywordID into grupo
                        select new
                        {
                            keywordId = grupo.Key,
                            Count = grupo.Count()
                        };
```